I dont understand how the discriminant works on this question?
I was wondering if someone could help me understand why my solution is wrong?
Practice Paper Question:

The graph of $y =\frac{1}{a+bx+4ax^2}$, where $a> 1$, has only one asymptote when
$$A)-5<b<5$$
$$B)b\leq -4a \text{ or }b\geq4a$$
$$C)-1\leq b \leq 4$$
$$D) b < -4a \text{ or } b > 4a$$

Correct Answer: C
My Answer: D
My Solution:

Because we want $1$ asymptote, we want to find solutions where there is only $1$ case for the denominator to be $0$. So solve for $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = 0$ so we want to solve for $$b^2-4\cdot 4a\cdot a=0$$ which is $$b^2=16\cdot a^2$$ so $$b=\pm4a$$
and when you apply the values of $a>0$ I get $$b<-4a \text{ or } b>4a$$ which is D, if someone can tell me where I went wrong I'd really appreciate that, thank you!


if $b=4a$, then you do not have either $b<-4a$ or $b>4a$ (similar for $b=-4a$).

Note that as $x\to\pm\infty$, $a+bx+4ax^2\to\text{sgn}(a)\infty$, as $a\ne0$. So $y$ already has one horizontal asymptote $y=0$. This means you actually need $a+bx+4ax^2$ is always nonzero, thus $$\Delta=b^2-16a^2<0\implies -4a<b<4a$$
Since $a>1$, this means $-4a<-4\le b\le4<4a$. Thus C is the answer.

Oh that's right, I forgot to consider the Horizontal Asymptote, thank you very much

Here the denominator can’t have any zero locus, so it should be $b^2<16a^2$.
Just image it, two sides of the zero locus $x_0$ of the denominator will induce two asymptotes.

Thank you very much, this was helpful
